# For what purpose Django is used for?

Tags: python, django

I heard a lot of people talking about Django on various forums. But I am having a very basic question : What is meant by Framework and why Django is used.

After listening a lot about Django, I ran few chapters for Django (from Djangobook.com). After running these chapters,  I am wondering how Django can be used to create a very simple website. (Website should have few pages like Home, Favorites, About, Contact linked to each other and will be providing static content).

Can Django be used for creation of such website? I searched a lot on internet but couldn't find any relevant examples, I only encountered with the examples for creation of blog, forum sites etc. If Django can be used for creation of this website, what should be the approach.

Can someone please explain this basic term "Framework" and its significance?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework

Comment: I guess you better start reading from [What is a framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework)

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed and downvoted. The OP has already read up a little on the subject and is still confused. Furthermore, they have a particular query in mind. Giving wiki links is pointless.

Comment: If i had to look at wiki links, i could have done it by myself. Infact this is the first link google will return. I was looking for a answer in simple words :- What is the real purpose of usage of Django and what other methods can be used for creation of html websites. IS Django suitable for it.

Comment: if you have lots of spare time then ONLY try to use it. Otherwise time waster

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony Wellcome to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 48, accepted):

No. It's not for making websites. Your sample just sounds like you want plain old HTML.

Django is for creating web applications. That is, software, normally backed by a database, that includes some kind of interactivity, that operates through a browser.  A Framework provides a structure and common methods for making this kind of software.

Comment: Actually I am learning Python and want to use it for web development but was confused whether Django is to be used or not. So to just begin with simple web development with some forms etc, i should be looking for Python CGI tutorial?

Comment: Don't use CGI, it's so 1990! Yes, look at Django. It's not easy to deploy the first time on a real server, but stick with it!

Answer (score 8):

Django can be used to create dynamic high-security web applications. For creating a static website like the one you asked, HTML is enough.

Tutorial for creating a django application can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/).

Answer (score 8):

I think what you're looking for is a very simple CMS (Content Management System), there are many of those available in all kinds of languages/frameworks. Django has django-cms and mezzanine (among others).

What django is really awesome at is building dynamic websites really fast, you don't need to worry about most things, you just define your data model and off you go (almost). If you want to have a better insight into what's possible, have a look at the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/) (under "First Steps"), it gives you a good introduction to django and how to build websites using it.

Comment: CMS is not required for websites which are going to have static content as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @arulmr True, I read the question a bit to fast, if it's just static content, a CMS is of course not required.